# Is there a way to batch find locally stored songs in Apple.Music and add them to library?

Tags: itunes, apple-music

Most of time I use Apple.Music for listening to music (from Mac and iPhone). Also I have locally stored music library (~1000 songs). So I want to find each local song at Apple.Music and add it to my iTunes music library. Is there a way to do it batch?

Comment: I have Apple.Music subscription and I can listen songs from it. I just want to find analogues of my locally stored songs in Apple.Music and add them to my iTunes library.

Comment: I understand the fact that songs will disappear if I end use Apple.Music. I don't worry - for this case I have them locally.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't quite clear, so I'm making some assumptions here:
 - You're using a Mac, with iTunes.
 - You're either looking for a way to distinguish your own music from Apple Music for whatever reason (having non-DRMd versions of the songs in your own personal library)

I can't help you with the last part, but iTunes on the Mac (and I suppose Windows) stores **Apple Music** (extension m4p) files separately from **Your** music files (extension m4a, mp3, aac, etc)

Apple Stores Apple Music under the iTunes Library folder (which you can discover by going to the iTunes Preferences pane and looking at the last tab). Apple Music is typically stored under `/iTunes Media/Apple Music` whereas your music is stored under `/iTunes Media/Music`

Or you can execute a command like the following from the iTunes library folder that will list all the Apple Music files into a text document.

```
find . -name "*.m4p" -print > textfile.txt
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using a Mac and iTunes. I want something like "find analogue of each local song in Apple.Music and add if it exists add it to iTunes library".